# Rosetta Stone with wine

Tags: installation, wine, thunderbird, passphrase, enigmail

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and PlayOnLinux 4.0.14

I want to install Rosetta Stone on my system. Everything is working with wine, but Rosetta Stone does not detect the mounted language packages. I mounted them with furius.
What can I do that Rosetta Stone is recognizing the mounted language packages?

Thank you!
New Ubuntu User

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still wondering, I had the same issue and I fixed it by choosing the 'loop' option instead of 'fuse'.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the version of wine you are running does not work with Rosetta Stone, or contrarily, the version of Rosetta Stone you have doesn't work with wine.

Please verify your compatibility by cross referencing the reported suceese here:
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1867

Comment: If this is indeed the case, I'm sorry. You might consider a donation to the wine project to get it working, or a platform independent webapp such as livemocha.

Comment: Hello virtualxtc!
Thank you for your answer. 
I am using Rosetta Stone 3.4.5 and Wine 1.6
According to your link Rosetta Stone should work properly.

Rosetta Stone is working but does not find the mounted CD

Comment: Okay, at this point you'll have to wait for someone with wine installed to help you, or try elsewhere, perhaps here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=619250